# Построение графиков на Activity с помощью GraphView?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, graph

Как построить графики, данные брать из базы данных sqlite, таблиц в базе 6 и для каждой требуется построить график

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите 
[эту](https://github.com/jjoe64/graphview) библиотеку:
там пошагово расписано как подключить и как добавлять точки на график.

Далее точки вам нужно взять из sqlite, соответственно загляньте [сюда](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html)